# NGINX + Symfony - what is the internal directive redirecting to?

Tags: nginx, configuration, symfony

Over at the official NGINX docs, they have the following configuration for production-level Symfony:

```
# PROD
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
   # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
   # current version of your application, you should pass the real
   # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
   # FPM.
   # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
   # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
   # for more information).
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
   # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
   # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
   # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
   internal;
}
```

The full configuration file can be found [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/)

What is `internal` actually redirecting to?  The comments say that it removes the front controller from the URI, but I'm not entirely sure how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't redirect anything. It specifies how *external redirections*, i.e. locations like `http://example.com/app.php/some-path` should be handled; while set, they should return `404`, only allowing *internal redirections*. Conditions handled as internal redirections are listed in the documentation for [`internal` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal):

> Specifies that a given location can only be used for internal
>   requests. For external requests, the client error 404 (Not Found) is
>   returned. Internal requests are the following:
>
> - requests redirected by the `error_page`, `index`, `random_index`, and `try_files` directives;
> - requests redirected by the `X-Accel-Redirect` response header field from an upstream server;
> - subrequests formed by the `include virtual` command of the [ngx_http_ssi_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html) module and by the
>     [ngx_http_addition_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_addition_module.html) module directives;
> - requests changed by the `rewrite` directive.

Comment: Ah, so it's connected to the `try_files` directive above that location block.  The fallback is `app.php$is_args$args`, which is an internal redirect to the `app.php` location.